# Problems re-building modules getting SPI working on a bcm2832(RPi ZERO W)

Tags: kernel, spi

When I try to get SPI working on a bcm2832(RPi ZERO W) by re-building modules and solving the kernel bug, following [this post](https://ralimtek.com/raspberry%20pi/electronics/software/raspberry_pi_secondary_sd_card/), I am getting the following errors I could not get solved:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd linux
pi@raspberrypi:~/linux $ KERNEL=kernel
pi@raspberrypi:~/linux $ make bcmrpi_defconfig
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:590: bcmrpi_defconfig] Error 2
pi@raspberrypi:~/linux $
```

I am following exactly the instructions on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice, I posted text now.